# Why comments are not showing even though it's successfully saved on database?

Tags: mongodb, express, schema, ejs

When I do `console.log(comments)` it prints the ID of comments and when I do `console.log(post.comments.text)` it gives `undefined`. However, the comments are successfully saved in the database and

```
// COMMENT FUNCTION

router.post("/:id/comments", middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
  //look up for post using id
  Post.findById(req.params.id, function(err, post) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      req.flash("error", "something went wrong")
      res.redirect("/posts");
    } else {
      //Create comment
      req.body.comment.body = req.sanitize(req.body.comment.body);

      Comment.create(req.body.comment, function(err, comment) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          req.flash("error", "OOPS! something went wronng")
        } else {
          //add username and id to comment
          comment.author.id = req.user._id;
          comment.author.username = req.user.username;
          comment.save();
          post.comments.push(comment);
          post.save();
          console.log(post.comments.text);

          req.flash("success", "Comment added successfully");

          res.redirect("/posts/" + post._id);
          //console.log("comment is saved");
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: One possibility is that you redirect BEFORE the `post.save()` has finished so if that redirect request comes in quickly, the new post may not yet be committed to the database.  You can code for that, but not redirecting until the `post.save()` has completed by using a completion callback on the save.

Answer (score 0):

`post.comments` is an array. An array doesn't have a `text` field which is why it's undefined. If you want to log a single comment's text you need to address it by index like this:

```
console.log(post.comments[0].text);
```

Or you can loop through all of the comments in the array and print them individually like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < post.comments.length; i++) {
  console.log(post.comments[i].text)
}
```